# Python SMTP stuck with no error

Tags: python, email, outlook, gmail

I'm using python 2.7 with the package that is installed with ArcGIS 10.5, which is what I also run on the servers. We have access to python 3, but it is unused. I'm trying to setup a python script to send emails like I have done in the past, but I keep getting my code stuck at this point with no errors.

```
self.smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)
```

I have tried using gmail and outlook, but it makes so difference. I have tried it on multiple machines and servers, but cannot get it to work. Can you still use python to send emails using gmail and outlook?

I can get it to error out when I use port 456, but using port 587 just gets stuck.

Rest of the code:

```
`def sendEmail(self, recipient, subject, message):
            try:
                self.smtp = smtplib.SMTP(self.server, self.port)
                self.smtp.ehlo()
                self.smtp.starttls()
                self.smtp.login(self.username, self.password)
                self.smtp.sendmail(self.username, recipient, message)`
```

Comment: Could you give some more context around the code it's hard to troubleshoot just one line of code.

Comment: Editing code into post.

Comment: If it's anything like requests, this might be due to a lack of a timeout parameter, i might be entirely wrong though. Docs do state it as an optional parameter.

Comment: I can add a 300 second timeout, but then my except will just loop back to the try and keep timing out without information.